# marker augmented reality

Tags: marker

About the augmented reality. I'm trying to change the marker (color, size) but I found the sofware who run with a marker in white and black and with a square shaped

can you help me to found solutions to change marker ??

thanks

Comment: This doesn’t particularly sound like a programming question. If it is, you need to provide *way* more information.

Comment: What product or technology or platform are you talking about?

Comment: TLI: too *little* information.

Answer (score 0):

Check out free [Mobile SDK](http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/) by metaio. It also offers 2D planar markers tracking that is not limited to black/white only.